# Question Fix Solution Suggestions, etc

Tags: discussion

**I'm not always good at asking political questions** which I post on this non-meta community from time to when when I hear or read about something potentially political that I think is a good question to ask.

**The problem I have is writing questions appropriately/correctly for this community** or perhaps being harsh or pointing out bad things specifically when I submit the question.

I learn sometimes it takes **an edit by someone that can give me an example** by editing my own post to learn as was the case most recently with as kind edit made on [Reasons Congress would censure Trump and what that'd mean](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/23799/reasons-congress-would-censure-trump-and-what-thatd-mean).

**Question:** How might I apply this same sort of fix to the [Do black people in America really face tougher consequences for the same crime committed by a white person?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/16374/do-black-people-in-america-really-face-tougher-consequences-for-the-same-crime-c) post, or would someone be so kind to give me some starting points or fixes they see.

- I think it is a good question that I asked in the wrong way so
  curious if someone can show me how I might be able to fix this
  question to make it as appropriate as possible.
- I'd rather not delete it or request my account be disassociated from it and would really want to fix it if someone can see any potential ways I should edit to ask differently, etc.

Comment: A look at the [revision history](https://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/16374/revisions) for that post may help explain why it was poorly received.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a few things I found obviously inappropriate:

---

> the lyrics having a personal meaning to Snoop Doggy Dog

The whole section about Snoop could be reduced to something like "*a popular entertainer feels that XXX.*", where "XXX" is the central point of the question.

**What inspired the submission of this question might be interesting, but it is irrelevant to the question itself.**

> The rapper also listed his many issues with President Trump

I'm sure there are also people that don't like Trump because his government is still giving too many handouts to people living on welfare.

**That someone has strong opinions about the President is irrelevant to the question.**

> If you don't understand still then you just likely don't understand nor will you unless it ever impacts or affects you.

You mention "you" four times.

**Commenting about the people reading this question is irrelevant to the question.**

> This will likely need some stats of reference if you can find them.

Having stats *is* relevant to the question, but it should be the questioner that provides the initial set of data.
The question can then ask whether the presented stats are reliable and representative, not simply cherry picked to prove a point.

Failing to provide the results of initial research (which should be presented as fact, not as opinion) makes the question seem lazy.

**Giving someone's opinion, rather than providing real statistics and examples, is an inappropriate way of asking a question on StackExchange sites.**

---

If all the noise and irrelevancies are removed from this item, there is no substance left other than the question in the title.

That question itself may very well be a good question, and quite suitable for this site, but the body of the question is essentially empty.

Comment: Thanks Ray, I'll use to advice to see what I can come up with to try to fix it. Good points to help clarify specific things wrong to potentially fix.